# font-size percentage with respect to container

Tags: html, css

how to change font-size with respect to its container.

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid #ff0">
    <span style="font-size: 18px">Test</span>
</div>
```

Now if i resize my window the container is also resized but the font-size remain of fix size, i want to change the font-size according to its container. Possible?

Comment: if you use SASS, then you can use a variable to store a value and set the sizes using the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using javascript / jquery you can do this: http://www.pukkared.com/?p=996

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Can anyone post a valid answer?